# OP Amp weird output

Tags: operational-amplifier

Can anyone explain why the output is so distorted and weird?

Circuit
[image]

Waveform
[image]

Comment: How is the op amp powered?

Comment: What were you expecting the output to look like?

Answer (score 3):

You have the op-amp connected a comparator, with the (+)input as the feedback node. In other words, you are using positive feedback.

If you want a linear amplifier, then you must use the (-)input as the feedback node. Swap the (+) and (-)inputs in your circuit.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty much what I'd expect to see for an opamp configured as a comparator with a small amount of positive feedback.

If you we're trying to create a high gain linear amplifier swap the input pins to get negative feedback and a gain of about twenty.